# Cname redirect to heroku?

Tags: ssl, heroku, https

I have an application on Heroku. I cname-redirect https://login.zenconomy.se to https://boomeranglogin.herokuapp.com/

I get the following (yellow) error in chrome:

This is probably not the site you are looking for!
You attempted to reach login.zenconomy.se, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as *.herokuapp.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake (and potentially harmful) version of login.zenconomy.se.
You should not proceed, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use SSL and HTTPS on Heroku with a custom hostname (like `login.zenconomy.se`), you have to purchase the SSL endpoint add-on, get a certificate and configure the setup as [described on Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint).